# .htaccess not matching

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get, apache2

htaccess not matching

```
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}           ^/catalog/products_in_scene.php?(.*)$
RewriteRule     ^(.+)                    "/services/hpv/index.php?%1"


RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}           ^/shop/derivation_tree.php?(.*)$
RewriteRule     ^(.+)                    "/services/dt/index.php?%1"
```

The top one matches fine with all the GET variables, the second one matches and sends me to the right page but never sends it the GET variables; Why?

Comment: I see no reason why it should work even in first place. `%{REQUEST_URI}` contains PATH part of URL **only** (`/catalog/products_in_scene.php` in your case). To match query string use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PATTERN_HERE`. But in any case -- query string is passed **unchanged** to new destination (if new URL has not provided own query string). You can always pass original query string using `[QSA]` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quote from your RewriteRule.

If it doesn't work, that mean there is something wrong in you php GET variable.

Answer (score 0):

You'd do better to use the `[QSA]` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^/shop/derivation_tree.php  /services/dt/index.php [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^catalog/products_in_scene\.php$ services/hpv/index.php [R,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^shop/derivation_tree\.php$ services/dt/index.php [R,L,NC]
```